# Is there a way to implement a countdown within a window, without the window freezing?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time
q1 = [
        [sg.Text("Question 1!"), sg.Button("x", visible=False), sg.Text("Time:"), sg.Text(" ", size=(10,1), key="t")],
        [sg.Text("This is where question 1 will be?")],
        [sg.Button("Option 1", key="1",button_color=("#ffffff","#151515")), sg.Button("Option 2", key="2",button_color=("#00ff00", "#151515"))],
        [sg.Button("Option 3", key="3",button_color=("#00ffff", "#151515")), sg.Button("Option 4", key="4",button_color=("#ff00ff", "#151515"))],
        [sg.Button("Submit"), sg.Button("Next Question"), sg.Button("Skip")]
    ]

window = sg.Window("Question 1",q1)

while True:
    event, values = window.Read()
    if event is None:
        break

    seconds = 20
    for i in range(seconds):
        seconds = seconds - i
        window.FindElement("t").Update(seconds)
        time.sleep(1)
```

I'm not sure if I am approaching this the correct way, but I want to make it so that a 20-second timer appears in the upper right corner. However, with the code above, no timer starts, and when you press a button, it freezes the program for 20 seconds.

Comment: Are you just using the timer to show the user how much time is left and when it reaches zero you want to quit?

Comment: @DJSchaffner Yeah the idea is so that if the time gets to 0 and they have not answered, it will skip to the next question. However, I also want to keep the time it took on each question so that I can display how long it took to take the quiz

Comment: 2 Options i think of right now would be A) run your timer in a different thread so it still counts down but doesnt block the main loop or B) use the `time` method from the `time` package. Then manually calculate your timer. I will go ahead and post an answer for option B)

Comment: I added an answer for how to do the timer. As for updating the timer in your window: I have not tried it myself but it seems you are supposed to do it like this `window['mykey'].update(textVar)`

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if this is discussed in the many notes in this post.  If so, feel free to ignore and sorry for taking up the space.

1. Never put a "sleep" in an event loop.  Use a timeout on your window.read instead
2. Call window.refresh() to have changes appear in your window:
   https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/call%20reference/#window
   It states:

> Use this call when you want something to appear in your Window immediately (as soon as this function is called). Without this call your changes to a Window will not be visible to the user until the next Read call

3. There is a timer demo - this demo and the concept of refreshing a window periodically is referenced throughout the documentation, in a demo program and also on Trinket.  The docs speak directly about having windows the appear to freeze if you don't call read or refresh periodically.  The timer is discussed here in the main docs:

https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#persistent-window-example-running-timer-that-updates

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to save your starting time and during each iteration of your main loop you calculate the time difference and update the timer.
When the difference reaches 20 seconds you stop and progress to the next question, otherwise you safe the current leftover time or whatever you want to do with it and start new.

Here is a basic example:

```py
from time import time

TIME_PER_QUESTION = 20.0

# Loop questions
for i in range(3):
  start = time()
  current = time()
  time_left = TIME_PER_QUESTION

  while time_left > 0:
    # Update your interface
    # doStuff()... update()...

    # Spam a bit for testing
    print("Leftover time {:.0f}".format(time_left))

    # Update current time and our timer
    current = time()
    time_left = TIME_PER_QUESTION - (current - start)
```

Of course you could add more ways to break out of the loop and store the leftover time while you do etc. and progress to the next question.

There are more ways to achieve this but thats one thing you could to. (This technique is mainly used for main loops in games and stuff like that)
As mentioned in the comments you could probably also do it using a threaded timer function if you want to.

**EDIT**
As for updating the text in the gui, I'm not sure if the way you do it works but if you say it never updated maybe try this instead:

```py
window['t'].update("{:.0f}".format(time_left))
```

Comment: I sort of understand the code you have provided, but how would I implement it. I tried to implement it, however, the timer still does not appear

Comment: Just replace the `for` loop you wrote for the timer in your question with the `while` loop in my example (together with the necessary variables of course)

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm implementing it wrong, but the timer is not appearing, and I still get the window freezing issue. The timer definitely works, as i can see it appearing, but it doesnt on the GUI, which also freezer

Comment: @Mr-Nightmare are you using `update` oder `Update`? Python is case sensitive and from what i found in the docs it is spelled with lower case u. If this does not work i fear something is wrong with the pysimplgegui code you provided. If so, i cannot really help you since i have not worked with it myself. What happens when you leave out the inner while loop i gave in the example and just keep updating the timer without stopping?

Comment: The same thing happens. I have always used Update instead of update and on other programs it works

Comment: I have solved it. Your program works. Howeveri had to add window.refresh() after the update line. Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: Nice to hear, glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

I needed to build something similar and I used @Mike from PSG 's example timer above and cut it way down to basics.

```
def binary_timed(time_allowed=15,default_value=False,query='no text inputed'):
    """
    This is a GUI that will present a user with a 'query' which is a string
    it gives them a number of seconds to make a binary choice and returns
    a default value when the time runs out
    """
    #layout options for the GUI
    layout = [
                 [sg.Text(query)],#
                 [sg.Text('time remaining: %s'%time_allowed,key='timer')],
                 [
                     sg.Button('Yes'),
                     sg.Button('No'),
                 ]
             ]
    
    #present the user with the gui
    window = sg.Window('binary_timed', layout)
    time_passed = 0
    while (True):
        event, values = window.read(timeout=1000)#1000 ms -> 1s wait between read
        time_passed += 1
        time_remaining = time_allowed-time_passed
        window['timer'].update("time remaining: %s"%time_remaining)
        if event != sg.TIMEOUT_KEY: #a button has been pressed 
            window.close()
            break
        if time_remaining == 0:
            window.close()
            break
        
    #evauluate our results
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED: return default_value #pressed the exit button
    if event == sg.TIMEOUT_KEY: return default_value
    if event == 'Yes': return True
    if event == 'No': return False
```

Using mine as a basis I applied the timeout concept to yours. Hopefully this helps and makes things understandable.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
q1 = [
        [sg.Text("Question 1!"), sg.Button("x", visible=False), sg.Text("Time:"), sg.Text(" ", size=(10,1), key="t")],
        [sg.Text("This is where question 1 will be?")],
        [sg.Button("Option 1", key="1",button_color=("#ffffff","#151515")), sg.Button("Option 2", key="2",button_color=("#00ff00", "#151515"))],
        [sg.Button("Option 3", key="3",button_color=("#00ffff", "#151515")), sg.Button("Option 4", key="4",button_color=("#ff00ff", "#151515"))],
        [sg.Button("Submit"), sg.Button("Next Question"), sg.Button("Skip")]
    ]

    
window = sg.Window("Question 1",q1)
time_elapsed = 0
time_remaining = 20
while True:
    event, values = window.read(1000)
    time_remaining -= time_elapsed
    window['t'].update(time_remaining)
    time_elapsed += 1
    if event != sg.TIMEOUT_KEY: #a button has been pressed 
            window.close()
            break
    if time_remaining == 0:
        window.close()
        break
```